# CURL request doesn't work in PHP (but it's work in command line)

Tags: php, curl, request, resolve

The curl request works in command line but doesn't work with php. I know it works with node.js too.

I also know I have to be in the same country as the service. For the moment the service returns that I'm not in the right country but I don't understand why. CURLOPT_RESOLVE seems to be the problem.

```
$params = array(
'origin' => 'Strasbourg',
'destination' => 'Paris (Toutes gares intramuros)',
'directTravel' => false,
'asymmetrical' => false,
'professional' => false,
'customerAccount' => false,
'oneWayTravel' => true,
'departureDate' => '2017-07-26T00:00:00',
'returnDate' => null,
'travelClass' => 'SECOND',
'passengers' => array(
    'travelerId' => null,
    'profile' => 'adult',
    'age' => 26,
    'fidelityCardType' => 'NONE',
    'fidelityCardNumber' => null,
    'commercialCardType' => 'NONE'
),
'withRecliningSeat' => false,
'physicalSpace' => null);

$resolve = array(sprintf(
   "%s:%d:%s", 
   '<the url without https://>',
   443,
   '127.0.0.1'
));

$headers[] = 'Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8';
$headers[] = 'Content-length: 0';

$url = "<the url in https>";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US))');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, $resolve);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$output = curl_exec ($ch); 

curl_close ($ch);
```

The command line curl :

```
curl -i -k -X POST -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US))" -H "Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*" --resolve "<the url without https://>:443:127.0.0.1" -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" -d '{"origin":"Strasbourg","destination":"Paris (Toutes gares intramuros)","directTravel":false,"asymmetrical":false,"professional":false,"customerAccount":false,"oneWayTravel":true,"departureDate":"2017-07-26T00:00:00","returnDate":null,"travelClass":"SECOND","passengers":[{"travelerId":null,"profile":"ADULT","age":26,"fidelityCardType":"NONE","fidelityCardNumber":null,"commercialCardType":"NONE"}],"withRecliningSeat":false,"physicalSpace":null}' '<the url in https>'
```

I get an error for the CURLOPT_RESOLVE option :

```
Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: Invalid curl configuration option
```

Any idea ?

Comment: `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` is not a valid option for `curl_setopt()`. See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for the complete list.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Well done I had an old version of php. I just upgrade to 5.6 and the request returns no error. But it seems i'm not in the right country to use the service. Do you know how can I resolve that ?